# What is a GitLab locked artifact?

Tags: gitlab

In the table `ci_job_artifacts` there is a column called `locked`. What does this column do? It's not documented in the [Job Artifacts API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts)? It's currently a `smallint` and it has 3 possible values: 0, 1, 2.

```
SELECT locked, count(*)
FROM ci_job_artifacts
GROUP BY locked;
 locked | count  
--------+--------
      0 |  18140
      1 |   2252
      2 | 203191
(3 rows)
```

[Even though I guess it should be?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/spec/fixtures/api/schemas/job/artifact.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to [the Locable mixin](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/models/concerns/ci/lockable.rb),

```
# `locked` will be populated from the source of truth on Ci::Pipeline
# in order to clean up expired job artifacts in a performant way.
# The values should be the same as `Ci::Pipeline.lockeds` with the
# additional value of `unknown` to indicate rows that have not
# yet been populated from the parent Ci::Pipeline
enum locked: {
  unlocked: 0,
  artifacts_locked: 1,
  unknown: 2
}, _prefix
```